# ListView unresponsive when host LinearLayout animateLayoutChanges is true

Tags: android

**Goal:** If at least one ListView item is selected, fade in a button. Fade out the button if no items are selected.

**Problem:** It's working, but the ListView becomes unresponsive for 1 - 2 seconds after an item is selected. I.e. I am unable to select other items in the ListView.

If I remove the `animateLayoutChanges` attribute from the LinearLayout, the ListView remains responsive.

Here is the simplified layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true">
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/category_listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/category_list_border"
    android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
    android:divider="@color/material_grey_400"
    android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
    android:padding="0.5dp" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/study_button"
    android:visibility="gone"
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:text="@string/study_now" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the code which sets the visibility of the button:

```
itemListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View selectedView, int position, long rowId) {
            Log.d(TAG, "List item selected");
            if (itemListView.getCheckedItemCount() == 0) {
                studyNowButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                studyNowButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

        }
    });
```

This occurs in the `onCreateView` lifecycle method of a fragment if that is relevant.

Comment: Have you tried using INVISIBLE instead of GONE.
OR
Try setting alpha for the buttons to 0.5f and disable the click.

Comment: @Mayank Surprisingly this works. Documentation states that I should be able to use either View.Gone or View.Invisible. However, I still need the button to collapse.

Comment: Actually you cant. View.GONE make the view puff like it was never there. INVISIBLE is like setting the alpha to 0.0f. So with View.GONE the list has to accomodate to the remaining size to got.

Comment: @Mayank Actually, you can. As per documentation: Views inside a ViewGroup can go through an appearing and disappearing animation when you add them to or remove them from a ViewGroup or when you call a View's setVisibility() method with VISIBLE, android.view.View#INVISIBLE}, or GONE. I understand the difference between View.GONE and View.INVISIBLE. I chose View.GONE for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove animateLayoutChanges from layout XML file. It tries to apply the transition everytime you select a list item. You should apply the transition only when the first item is selected or all items are unselected.

You can try adding the transition programmatically using [LayoutTransition](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/LayoutTransition.html)

Answer (score 0):

Change the `View.GONE` to `View.INVISIBLE`